# Apache UserGrid won't start

Tags: tomcat7, war, usergrid

```
SEVERE: Context [] startup failed due to previous errors
```

2016-09-02 10:47:04,606 INFO (http-bio-8080-exec-1) [org.apache.usergrid.rest.ShutdownListener] - ShutdownListener invoked
2016-09-02 10:51:13,857 ERROR (http-bio-8080-exec-6) [org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader] - Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'usergridSystemMonitor' defined in class path resource [usergrid-core-context.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'version' in string value "${version}"; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'version' in string value "${version}"
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.doProcessProperties(PlaceholderConfigurerSupport.java:209)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.processProperties(PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyResourceConfigurer.postProcessBeanFactory(PropertyResourceConfigurer.java:84)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:696)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:671)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:461)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:5010)

Answer (score 0):

You need to update value of property **usergrid.version.build** in **usergird-deployment.properties** file

Best,